# Request timed out when pinging wireless router

Tags: networking, wifi, ping, wireless

Recently I noticed the internet running very slowly on my laptop, which is connected to my wireless network (Netgear DGN2000).

When I ping the router, I get long ping times and/or request timed out...here's an output:

```
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=20ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=108ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=48ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=14ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=221ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=87ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
```

This has only started in the last week. When I connect to the router with a cable, the ping time is <1ms (albeit with the very occasional request timed out). I'm running Win7 on a Sony VAIO VPCEH.

What would cause this? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several issues that can cause this kind of behavior

1. There is an electromagnetic interference on this channel, try checking if a neighbor of yours just setup a new network, and scan the available networks and their channels (There's a great Android app for that: [Wifi Analyzer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer)), then, setup your wireless connection on a free channel (notice that channels 1 6 and 11 are the only channels that do not overlap each other).
2. Your router is inside a concrete walled room, and it's struggling to receive and transmit to the other rooms in your house (How good is your reception ?).
3. Resetting the router helps from time to time, like magic :)

Comment: I have actually tried the laptop literally right next to the router. Wouldn't this discount options 1 and 2 you suggest? The connection strength is "Excellent" also.

I've also reset the router, no difference.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: I don't know if this is a coincidence, but I just changed the channel to 6 and it has been working fine for some time with an average ping of about 3ms. Does this indicate that it was probably interference from another network?

Comment: It may be the case, It can also be other devices, such as 2.4GHz cordless telephones.

Comment: Actually, my cordless telephone wasnt previously plugged in, and I plugged it in a week or so ago. I guess that explains it!

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem.
I was using a static IP & DNS serser in my Network connection; I tried to remove the static and let computer takes an IP automatically from internet router and this makes the problem disappear and PING time becomes 1 or 2ms (it was about 2000ms before)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem (router Netgear WNR3500L) with IGMP proxying enabled (WAN setup in the Advanced section of the official firmware admin interface). Default setting is "disabled" though.